# Limit user registration by email domain

Tags: users

I want to allow people only with an email ending with a specific format and domain such as foo.bar@mail.school.edu to register for the site that I am building. How can I do this in the Admin Tool Bar?

Comment: You have to achieve this by doing programmatically.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that because I am new to Drupal. Maybe there are some modules that allow this to be done easily. However, if this is the only way, do you how I can do this programmatically, or where I can find resources to learn how to do this through code?

Comment: Checkout this module also https://www.drupal.org/project/email_domain_restriction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [domain_registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_registration) to allow or dissalow emails from certain domains to register.

Setup is very simple as seen from the instructions on the project page

> 1. Install the module
> 2. visit 'admin/config/system/domain_register'
> 3. Choose if you want to only allow, or disallow the domains from registering
> 4. Enter the domain names you wish to allow/deny (one per line) in the format of 'foo.com'. Wildcards are allowed.
> 5. Enter the error message you wish to show to the end user if the email address
>      doesn't validate

Comment: @ElectroMotiveHorse Glad I was able to help.  If the question has helped or answered your question please consider voting and or accepting the answer.   Voting is central in stackexhange sites and here is the reasoning https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote

Comment: The answer has been accepted but I do not have enough rep to vote yet in drupal answers.